# Copy a view from one database to another database on the same server

Tags: sql-server, view, metadata

I want to copy a view from one database to another database, on the **same** server. Both databases are structured exactly the same, except for about 8 views added in one.

Comment: Powershell and the script method of the corresponding SMO class will do this in a trice.

Answer (score 5):

Basic method:

1. Right click on the view in SQL Server Management Studio
2. Save as script to new query window
3. Change context to target database
4. Execute script

This is basically correct, but this will not preserve permissions on the views. A better way is to:

1. Right-click the database
2. Choose Tasks -> Generate Scripts -> Choose Objects -> Select specific database objects
3. Choose your views -> next
4. Click the [Advanced] button and then [Script Object-Level Permissions] should be set to True (default is False)

Answer (score -5):

Another way you can execute below query;

```
select * into [destination_db_name].[dbo].[viewname]
from [source_db_name].[dbo].[viewname]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This will copy the data. I think the questioner wants the view definitions, however.

Comment: yes,but schema also will be copied.

Comment: It will create and populate a new *table* called "viewname". It will not create a view over existing tables in the destination database.

Comment: yes, you are right. my mistake.

Comment: @MichaelGreen can you tell me how to delete this answer.

Comment: @Himanshu there is a link just below your answer: "delete". We can try to delete it for you but it may take more time (needs 3 or 5 votes)